# Retrieving the latest post that belongs to a specific use in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to retrieve the latest post that belongs to a user.  First I retrieve all the posts that belong to a specific user and store them in an instance variable.  What should I do after that to get the latest post from those that are now stored in the instance variable?

```
@user_posts = user.posts

????
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this:

```
@last_post = user.posts.last
```